# Integrating Salesforce API's in IBM Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud

What would be the most appropriate way to integrate Salesforce API's in a Bluemix Node.js application?

Answer (score 0):

As of right now there is not a Salesforce service in Bluemix.  What you could do is store your connection information in environment variables.  You can do this with `cf set-env appname env value`.

Additionally you could create a user provided service to store your credentials as well. You can do this with `cf create-user-provided-service`.

http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/user-provided.html

Comment: What about using the Cloud integration service with the Cast Iron option. As far as I am informed cast iron contains an adapter for Salesforce. Unfortunately I have no experience with this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest creating an Authenticated App in Salesforce.  This is configured in Salesforce Setup with a few clicks. After that is done you can query the Salesforce data from the Bluemix Node.js app.  See this blog for a nice walkthrough and example.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-mobile-phonebook-app/

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Integration Service](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#services/CloudIntegration/index.html#gettingstartedwithcloudintegation) with the option for Cast Iron Live

Cast Iron Live knows the Salesforce API/Object Model

http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/cast-iron-cloud-integration/salesforce-integration/

I have not used the SalesForce integration, but the principle is equal to Google APIs/ Microsoft CRM APIs etc...